# Why are breakpoints in tests not hit?

Tags: c#, nunit, automated-tests, breakpoints, nunit-2.6

I have several NUnit tests in a test project that is part of a solution. I have a breakpoint in each test method. A "typical" one of these methods is:

```
public void TestHHSInterface()
{
    var HHSClient = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSClient>();

    var s = HHSClient.GetTestMessage("Duckbilled", "Platypus");

    Assert.Greater(s.Value.Length, 0);
}
```

The tests run, as evidenced by what I see here:

[image]

Is this normal that breakpoints are not hit? It seems that they are running, but that the results (passed 3, failed 0) are not really valid, because I added test code that SHOULD fail, yet no matter what, the tests "succeed."

What am I doing wrong, or omitting here?

### UPDATE

Okay, I downloaded/installed NUnit Test Adapter, right-clicked the test shown above, and selected "Debug Tests"

My breakpoint was hit, and I was able to step over the first line, but then it blew up; this is what I see in the Output pane (I know this is probably "TMI," but I don't know what's pertinent and what is not - I cut out the middle, as my post was too long):

> 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM
>   FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM
>   FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM
>   FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded . . . .
>
> 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES
>   (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\msdia120typelib_clr0200.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\62b76a75\bbee3246_019acf01\CStore.Integration.Tests.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\8379df6f\6a4e7a10_1f92cf01\Castle.Windsor.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\4c09b93f\71022b68_fc99cf01\HHS.Client.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\d29638a9\7a8b1a66_fc99cf01\CStore.DomainModels.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\3926c47b\2e2ff20f_1f92cf01\Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\e881bc9e\8fb83744_0896cf01\CStore.Common.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\21c8b534\60cca60f_1f92cf01\Castle.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\28a3025a\10087044_0896cf01\MapStores.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\a137cbd9\253adc44_0896cf01\HBaseMapStore.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\07c00fd2\f8f7a644_0896cf01\MQProcessing.MQPutService.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\bae09939\c8a9ee66_fc99cf01\CStore.Data.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\a22b9b5d\688b1868_fc99cf01\CSPoll.Client.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\30e797f5\2901ac44_0896cf01\CStore.Common.HTTP.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\4590d591\2f177866_fc99cf01\DeviceConfig.Client.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\247d65ee\763b5c67_fc99cf01\CStore.Client.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\f5f7b992\7e1ebf67_fc99cf01\CStore.BusinessObjects.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\c8d39645\9db0b068_fc99cf01\MQProcessingWCFServices.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\6a87a030\23c15269_fc99cf01\HHS.API.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\ba0add0f\0aa77e66_fc99cf01\CStore.Data.Legacy.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\82c78164\30882368_fc99cf01\CStore.BusinessObjects.HHS.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted
>   DynamicMethods Assembly'.  'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'CastleDictionaryAdapterAssembly'.  The thread 0x27f4 has exited with
>   code 259 (0x103). The thread 0xaa4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
>   The thread 0x1c70 has exited with code 259 (0x103). The thread 0x2578
>   has exited with code 259 (0x103). 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\ac0d956f\b951e91a_1f92cf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http.WebRequest\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred
>   in System.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
>   occurred in System.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Exception' occurred in HHS.Client.dll A first chance exception
>   of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'NUnit.Core.NUnitException' occurred in nunit.core.dll The thread
>   0x2128 has exited with code 259 (0x103). The thread 0x28a0 has exited
>   with code 259 (0x103). The thread 0x29d8 has exited with code 259
>   (0x103). 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2):
>   Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\0501e887\ab9f7e46_019acf01\HHS.Web.Tests.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\768b7768\f8a3911b_1f92cf01\nunit.framework.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\62b76a75\bbee3246_019acf01\CStore.Integration.Tests.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\8379df6f\6a4e7a10_1f92cf01\Castle.Windsor.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\4c09b93f\71022b68_fc99cf01\HHS.Client.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\d29638a9\7a8b1a66_fc99cf01\CStore.DomainModels.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\3926c47b\2e2ff20f_1f92cf01\Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\e881bc9e\8fb83744_0896cf01\CStore.Common.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\21c8b534\60cca60f_1f92cf01\Castle.Core.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\28a3025a\10087044_0896cf01\MapStores.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\a137cbd9\253adc44_0896cf01\HBaseMapStore.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\07c00fd2\f8f7a644_0896cf01\MQProcessing.MQPutService.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\bae09939\c8a9ee66_fc99cf01\CStore.Data.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\a22b9b5d\688b1868_fc99cf01\CSPoll.Client.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\30e797f5\2901ac44_0896cf01\CStore.Common.HTTP.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\4590d591\2f177866_fc99cf01\DeviceConfig.Client.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\247d65ee\763b5c67_fc99cf01\CStore.Client.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\f5f7b992\7e1ebf67_fc99cf01\CStore.BusinessObjects.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\c8d39645\9db0b068_fc99cf01\MQProcessingWCFServices.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\6a87a030\23c15269_fc99cf01\HHS.API.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\ba0add0f\0aa77e66_fc99cf01\CStore.Data.Legacy.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\82c78164\30882368_fc99cf01\CStore.BusinessObjects.HHS.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'Anonymously Hosted
>   DynamicMethods Assembly' 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR
>   v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'CastleDictionaryAdapterAssembly' 'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\10796_635403224540977618\Tests_5885246\assembly\dl3\ac0d956f\b951e91a_1f92cf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http.WebRequest\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll'
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll A
>   first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll The thread 0x1050 has exited with code 259
>   (0x103). The thread 0x24a0 has exited with code 259 (0x103). A first
>   chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll A first
>   chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll A first chance
>   exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll A first chance exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll The program
>   '[10796] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited
>   with code 0 (0x0). The program '[10796]
>   vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Are you debugging? Breakpoints don't hit if you're not running in the debugger.

Comment: Sure; breakpoints in other parts of the code are hit, just not in the test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If breakpoints are not hit, then debugger is not attached (or code is not executed). I suggest you to use [NUnit test adapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) for Visual Studio. It will allow you to debug test right in place - just select test and chose *Debug selected test* in context menu.

Another option - you can [attach debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to NUnit GUI process and use [`Debugger.Break()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in test code.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon well, actually it looks like another question. From exception details I see that you have UnauthorizedAccessException. When exactly it happens? During `GetTestMessage` execution? Or during resolving `IHHSClient`? Are you making some network requests?

Comment: I find that the test runs if I have two instances of the solution (two separate instances of Visual Studio). If I run one, and then do the test on the other, the test runs and succeeds.