# Why is this NUnit test failing?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, nunit, webrequest, nunit-2.6

This is an "extension" of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614807/why-are-breakpoints-in-tests-not-hit)

I am now running two instances of Visual Studio / the solution. I start one, and then in the other I access the context menu for this test:

```
public enum HttpMethods
{
    GET = 0,
    PUT,
    POST,
    DELETE,
    HEAD,
    OPTIONS,
    LIST,
    UNKNOWN
}

[Test]
public HttpWebRequest TestHHSDeliveryItemInterfacePostPPTData()
{
    var DeliveryItem = IOC.container.Resolve<IHHSDeliveryItem>();

    string data = @"<note>
                        <to>Tove</to>
                        <from>Jani</from>
                        <heading>Reminder</heading>
                        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                    </note>";
    string uri = "http://localhost:21609/api/deliveryitems/InsertIntoPPTData";
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method =  //Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), HHTPMethods.).ToString();
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = request.ContentType;
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
    ((HttpWebRequest)request).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // never used
    byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
    using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
    }

    if (DeliveryItem.InsertIntoPPTData((HttpWebRequest)request))
    {
        return request as HttpWebRequest;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

...and select "Debug Test." Tragically, though, I (again) never reach the breakpoint I've set (on the first line above, the assignment to "DeliveryItem "). And the Output pane is then filled with the following logsam and dumpsam:

```
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly
\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. 
Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.GenericTestAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSPhoneAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.OrderedTestAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TfsLogger.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TmiAdapter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.ComInterfaces.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppPhoneUnitTestExtension.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.Composition
\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll'. 
Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.util.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly
\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\5280_635403276502133355\Tests_11081234\assembly\dl3\ed8d1526\6266a85f_0d9acf01\HHS.Web.Tests.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Loaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\5280_635403276502133355\Tests_11081234\assembly\dl3\aef8b6df\f8a3911b_1f92cf01\nunit.framework.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW
\msdia120typelib_clr0200.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x3bf4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x2a0c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\NUnitTestAdapter.1.0\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\5280_635403276502133355\Tests_11081234\assembly\dl3\ed8d1526\6266a85f_0d9acf01\HHS.Web.Tests.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: test-domain-HHS.Web.Tests.dll): Unloaded 'C:\Users\clay\AppData\Local\Temp\nunit20\ShadowCopyCache\5280_635403276502133355\Tests_11081234\assembly\dl3\aef8b6df\f8a3911b_1f92cf01\nunit.framework.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x2b7c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
The thread 0x2344 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
The program '[5280] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5280] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

***Note: I am able to successfully run simple tests in this manner; this one is problematic for some reason...***

### UPDATE

Okay, that was really bizarre: that code compiled, even though an assignment was commented out. It is now:

```
request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), HttpMethods.POST).ToString();
```

### UPDATE 2

I have replaced the return type of the method with void, and the if/else block at the end with:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(request);
```

### UPDATE 3

I had forgotten to add the line of code that actually sends the request (it doesn't seem real transparent to me the way it works), so after writing to the stream in using block I now have:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Assert.IsNotNull(response);
```

...but I'm still getting an epoch, if not epic fail:

*. . .
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x3114 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
The thread 0x3d7c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
The program '[12252] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12252] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).*

Comment: I didn't see any assert in you test, is it normal?

Comment: Good thought; I got so caught up in the "regular" code, I forgot the test code.

Comment: Which makes me wonder; since the pattern/standard is to always end with an Assert (so it seems to me, I'm a newb[ie,y] to unit testing) do tests always need to return void? Otherwise, if you return, as I am here, the Assert would not get reached.

Comment: Do you use a method with the attribute [SetUp]?
Why has your Test function a return value instead of void - what do you expect the unit test runner to do with that?

Comment: @BernhardHiller: See my last comment (I already changed that to void)